# Informatica workflow(MS SQL SERVER data source and target) fails error RR_4036"Data Source name not found and no default driver specified ."

Tags: dns, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, informatica-powercenter

I have windows 64bit and a Informatica client 32bit installed on it, so I added a DSN entry using the ODBC administrator for 32bit with driver native client "sql server" to connect to a Mssql 2008 R2 database on another pc. I added an entry in system DSN tab because informatica service is using System account. No problems when I have to import source and target in informatica using that ODBC DSN 32 bit "TARGET_DB_sciolto" (see odbc.ini below) entry. I build up my mapping and in the workflow session property than I change the connection from mssql server to ODBC.
The worflow is failing with same RR_4036 error.I think that the only thing I still have to try is to modify my ODBC.ini file since I read that I must add "enablequotedidentifiers=1" so I opened the file expecting to see a lot of entries but I only see following few lines and don't know what to do and would really appreciate if someone would help:

```
[ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
test_infa=SQL Server Native Client 10.0 (32 bit)
TARGET_DB_sciolto=SQL Server (32 bit)
Target_DB=SQL Server (32 bit)
[test_infa]
Driver32=C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sqlncli10.dll
[TARGET_DB_sciolto]
Driver32=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLSRV32.dll
[Target_DB]
Driver32=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLSRV32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up using lots of parameters. Please make sure you add the connection info in below format. Pls mention host,port,database at least. also make sure informatica machine has access to the datbase.

```
[TARGET_DB_sciolto]
Driver32=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SQLSRV32.dll
Description=DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol
AlternateServers=
AlwaysReportTriggerResults=0
AnsiNPW=1
ApplicationName=
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AuthenticationMethod=1
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
BulkLoadOptions=2
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
Database=<database_name>
EnableBulkLoad=0
EnableQuotedIdentifiers=0
EncryptionMethod=0
FailoverGranularity=0
FailoverMode=0
FailoverPreconnect=0
FetchTSWTZasTimestamp=0
FetchTWFSasTime=1
GSSClient=native
HostName=<SQL_Server_host>
HostNameInCertificate=
InitializationString=
Language=
LoadBalanceTimeout=0
LoadBalancing=0
LoginTimeout=15
LogonID=
MaxPoolSize=100
MinPoolSize=0
PacketSize=-1
Password=
Pooling=0
PortNumber=<SQL_Server_server_port>
QueryTimeout=0
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0
SnapshotSerializable=0
TrustStore=
TrustStorePassword=
ValidateServerCertificate=1
WorkStationID=
XML Describe Type=-10
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I saw your driver file name is " DWsqls27.so" mine "sqlncli10.dll" is there a reason? What if I install an informatica client 64 bit on the other pc where I have mssql server? If I let communicate  infa server of the machine 1' and infa client 64 bit on the other machine 2' do you think I will have to add less settings and will work smoothly?

Comment: Sorry, it should be SQLSRV32.dll or whatever is in your odbc.ini file. Now, i dont think less settings will work. And its just one time entry.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I pasted your parameters inserting port,database,hostname. Now I am getting Error : Failed to create and initialize SQL OLE DB instance. Reason 14007, token not found. I guess because the user running the query in informatica is not the same so. i went to regedit an I changed the owner of  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{2206CDB0-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A82" to Administrator. I also went to Dcomcnfg and I added there "Administrator" with all permissions. I am still getting same error.I don t  know how to solve it to debug the connection to the linked database

Comment: the user you mentioned in odbc.ini and in the connection string should be same and you should be able to connect to the DB using odbc. This is old qn, can you tell me, your infa server is also windows? if yes, then entry in that server matters. and pls use ODBC data source admin to setup and check connection. If its unix based, then use ssgodbc to test out the connection.

Comment: the ODBC data source admin of the pc where I installed infa server says Error 17 SQL server does not exist or access denied. Since I cannot see the SQL Server entry when I try to create a custom inbound rule on firewall for the database instance it is probably because I have to install something. This is why it says it doesn t exist right? what exactly do I have to install?

Comment: its access denied error which means u need to make sure DB port is accessible from infa.

Comment: .In  Infa PC I already create an inbound rule for port 1433 to allow connections and all the other pc are in the domain... I am not sure where I I have to try to telnet from , so i did reciprocally both tests using port 1433 but it says  "no connection can be established" either way. As I mentioned by creating custom rules in infa pc for the database instance I don t see entries for sql server services